# Get numbers around the key in array

Tags: php

Suppose I have an array like below

```
   [0] => 25
    [1] => 30
    [2] => 35
    [3] => 40
    [4] => 45
    [5] => 50
    [6] => 55
    [7] => 60
    [8] => 65
    [9] => 70
```

If i input my key as 4  , I need to get nearest 2 arrays , example

```
[2] => 35
[3] => 40
[4] => 45
[5] => 50
[6] => 55
```

right now I use something like below.

```
$key = 4;
$count = 2;
$slice = array_slice($array,$key-$count,4+($count-1));
```

But if my $key is 1 and count is 2, I need something like

```
    [0] => 25
    [1] => 30
    [2] => 35
    [3] => 40
```

and if key is 8 I need

```
  [6] => 55
    [7] => 60
    [8] => 65
    [9] => 70
```

I cannot achieve this slice code above , so some one guide some other way , thank you.

Comment: You probably need to check if `key-$count` is negative, and if so, then reset it to 0.

Comment: You could use `min()`/`max()` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Code satisfy your test cases

```
$array = array(
    '0' => 25,
    '1' => 30,
    '2' => 35,
    '3' => 40,
    '4' => 45,
    '5' => 50,
    '6' => 55,
    '7' => 60,
    '8' => 65,
    '9' => 70,
);

$key = 8;
$count = 2;

$slice = array_slice(
    $array, 
    ( ( $key - $count ) > 0 ) ? ( $key - $count) : 0  , 
    ( ( $key - $count ) > 0 ) ? ( (2 * $count) + 1 ) :  ( (2 * $count) + ( $key - $count + 1 )  )
);
```

Here is the online [demo](https://3v4l.org/ZpX4l)

Comment: what is 4 in your function ?

Comment: @Graciewilliams Updated. Please check.

Comment: @Graciewilliams There was some issue with the code when $count was anything other than 2. I have tested and updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the offset to `$key - $count` is correct. You can use `max()` to keep it from going negative.

```
$offset = max(0, $key - $count);
```

For the length, the basic calculation is `2 * $count + 1`. By adding `min($key - $count, 0)` to that, you can subtract any of the left-side count that would extend below zero.

```
$length = 2 * $count + 1 + min($key - $count, 0);
```

You don't need to worry if the slice extends beyond the count of the array, that part will be ignored.

```
$slice = array_slice($array, $offset, $length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean:

```
$slice = array_slice($array,$key-$count,**$key**+($count-1));
```

Just make sure you don't go negative:

```
$key = 4;
$count = 2;
if ( ($key - $count) < 0){
  $key = $count;
}
$slice = array_slice($array,$key-$count,$key+($count-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Erwin's answer is correct.

If you also want to ensure the same number of values are selected if a key at the end of the array is given you will need to check for this:

```
$key = 4;
$count = 2;
if ( ($key - $count) < 0){
  $key = $count;
} elseif ( ($key + $count) > count($array) ) {
  $key = count($array) - $count;
}
$slice = array_slice($array,$key-$count,$key+($count-1));
```